# Reference to an address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int arr[3]={1,2,3};
return 0;
}
```

Now what will `*(&arr)` give me and why? I want a detailed explanation. Don't just tell me how `*` and `&` cancel out :P

I want to know how the compiler interprets this expression to give the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&arr` creates a pointer to the array - it's of type `int (*)[3]`, and points at the array `arr`.

`*&arr` dereferences that pointer - it's the array itself.  Now, what happens now depends on what you do with it.  If you use `*&arr` as the subject of either the `sizeof` or `&` operators, then it gives the size or address of the array respectively:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof *&arr);    /* Prints 3 * sizeof(int) */
```

However, if you use it in any other context, then it is evaluated as a pointer to its first element:

```
int *x = *&arr;
printf("%d\n", *x);    /* Prints 1 */
```

In other words: `*&arr` behaves exactly like `arr`, as you would expect.

Comment: well, if i say printf(" %d ",*&arr); it just gives me the &arr[0], the address of the first element. Also when you say it creates a pointer, is it created physically?

Comment: It "creates it" in the same way that evaluating `2 + 3` "creates" the `int` value `5`.

Answer (score -1):

Since `arr` is a statically-allocated array, not a pointer **variable** - the expression `&arr` is equivalent to `arr`. Hence `*(&arr)` is actually `*arr`.

The thing would be different if `arr` was a pointer.

Comment: arr is not equivalent to &arr.

Comment: This is not true.  `*(&arr)` is the same as `arr`, which is manifestly *not* the same as `*arr`.